# How to move picture with the mouse? C# Forms

Tags: c#, forms, events, mouse

I want to move a pictureBox using my mouse so I got till here:

```
    private void pictureB_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, recLoc);
    }
    private void pictureB_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkAble = true;
        choosingPoint.X = e.X;
        choosingPoint.Y = e.Y; 
        lastPoint.X = e.X;
        lastPoint.Y = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureB_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WorkAble)
        {
            recLoc.X = e.X - choosingPoint.X;// + lastPoint.X;
            recLoc.Y = e.Y - choosingPoint.Y;// + lastPoint.Y;
            pictureB.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void pictureB_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkAble = false;
        lastPoint.X = e.X;
        lastPoint.Y = e.Y;
    }
    // recLoc = pictureBox Location.
```

well, it works great.. However not perfectly..
What I mean is once the KeyUp event is executed, and you click again the image will return to the 0, 0 point of the pictureBox.
To overcome that I added the lastPoint point and in the mouse move I add its values.
So in the one hand it does draw the image in the last dropped point, however the mouse will be on the 0, 0 point of to the image and not in the place I clicked - on the image. Like if I click on the center of the image the mouse will be on the 0, 0 point..

any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make incremental changes to "recLoc" to avoid losing the original location:

```
private void pictureB_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (WorkAble)
    {
        recLoc.X = recLoc.X + e.X - choosingPoint.X;
        recLoc.Y = recLoc.Y + e.Y - choosingPoint.Y;
        choosingPoint = e.Location;
        pictureB.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void pictureB_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkAble = true;
        lastPoint.X = e.X;
        lastPoint.Y = e.Y;
    }

        private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseMove = false;
            lastPointX = e.X;
            lastPointY = e.Y;
        }


private void pictureB_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (WorkAble)
    {
        recLoc.X -= (lastPoint.X - e.X);
        recLoc.Y -= (lastPoint.X - e.X);
        pictureB.Refresh();
        choosingPoint = e.Location;
    }
}
```